# Draw list of points in elm

Tags: javascript, elm

So I'am totally new to Elm and I am wondering how to draw a grid in elm:

I have a list of points, say `[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...,(9,9)]` and I want to draw a 9 times 9 "grid" with each "point" being a square (say 10 by 10 pixels) such that exactly the squares with the corresponding coordinates in the List are black (note I don't need any lines separating column or rows).

So the result in this case should simply be a "staircase" which runs diagonally from the bottom left to the top right.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGIO1.jpg)

> What is the best way to do this?

Googling around I found that maybe svg could be a possible solution, but unfortunately I don't know how svg works.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: show how should look the final result for your input `[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...,(9,9),(10,10)]`

Comment: i added a picture. ( I accidentally only drew a 9 times 9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Svg](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/latest/Svg) library works fine for this.

```elm
import Html
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)

plotSquares : List (Int, Int) -> Html.Html msg
plotSquares =
  let
    toSquare (a, b) =
      rect
        [ x (toString (a * 10))
        , y (toString (100 - (b * 10)))
        , width "10"
        , height "10" ] []
  in
    svg [ width "100", height "100" ] << List.map toSquare

main =
  plotSquares <| List.map (\x -> (x, x)) [1..9]
```

This example plots the staircase you describe, starting in the bottom left and ascending to the top right. You can paste the code into the http://elm-lang.org/try to give it a whirl.